# LInq Contains Operator Shows Design Time Error

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to filter a collection based on the contents of another collection using linq and EF 6.2.0. However, I am getting a design time error "Cannot resolve method Contains(string)". I could have sworn I used this in the past but it's not working now. What did I miss?

```
    private void UpdateCheckListItems(LMUpdateModel model, LoanResponse response)
    {
        var checkListItems = this.appData.LMLoanChecklist.Find(x => x.LMAutoID == model.LMAutoID);

        var codesToUpdate = checkListItems.Where(x => model.CheckListItems.Contains(x.LMCLCode));

       ... other code

    }
```

[image]

Comment: List of CheckListItem cannot contains string ... edit: haha funny stuff you have the right code on your image too

Comment: magic orb generated answer: ... `.Contains(x.LMCLCode)` should be `.Contains(c=>c.LMCLCode == x.LMCLCode)`

Comment: @selvin.I tried that but still had a design-time error. I really thought you could use a complex object.

Comment: But I did find that dropping the .Contains() and Replacing with .Any() did work. I updated my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I looked back over some other projects and found a sample of when I implemented it before. I solved it by loading the values I was searching into a list of `List<T>` and then adding the Contains on the new list. I thought you could use the value from a complex list but I guess not.

```
List<string> lmlcCodes = new List<string>();
foreach (var item in model.CheckListItems)
{
    var code = item.LMCLCode;
    lmlcCodes.Add(code);
}

var checkListItems = this.appData.LMLoanChecklist.Find(x => x.LMAutoID == model.LMAutoID).Where(x => lmlcCodes.Contains(x.LMCLCode));
```

I did find though that If I dropped the .Contains() and add the .Any() then this statement does work with the complex object.

```
var checkListItems = this.appData.LMLoanChecklist.Find(x => x.LMAutoID == model.LMAutoID).Where(cl => model.CheckListItems.Any(cl1 => cl1.LMCLCode == cl.LMCLCode)).ToList();
```